# Python Pandas read_excel map string to date

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the below code but 'Start Date' and 'End Date' remain as strings even after being I attempt to convert their datatypes when importing the data. How can I convert them to dates in my dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt 

df = pd.read_excel('sfdc_churn_report.xltx', 
                   index_col = None, 
                   dtype = {'Start Date': dt.date, 
                            'End Date': dt.date}
                  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *dtype* parameter, pass *parse_dates=['Start Date', 'End Date']*.

Assuming that your both date columns are formatted the standard way,
it should be enough.

If you have some "weird" date formatting, you can insted specify a converter
function, using *converters* parameter.

Passing *index_col* is not needed, as its default value is just *None*.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_excel('sfdc_churn_report.xltx', index_col="Date",parse_dates=True)
```

`parse_dates=True` will try its best to convert the string date to an actual date object.